# Interactive R terminal using system default R instead of R in a conda environment

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

The vscode is running on macOS, and the R is on a remote server(Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS). But the R interactive terminal uses a system default R(4.1.2), and I have created a conda environment and installed another R(4.2.2) before, how can I switch to the version 4.2.2 in vscode? Thanks! Although i change r.trem.linux: "/home/abc/miniconda3/envs/R/bin/radian" in the remote setting.json, it doesn't work.

1. Interactive R terminal using default system R

[image: 1]

2. R in conda

[image: 2]

actually i wanna use the R in conda as the interactive R terminal, but it used the system default R

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I tried to set the `r.rpath.linux` to the R path in the conda env but it was not recognized by vscode somehow. After a while I figured out a working solution, which is to specify the R path in the radian launching option `--r-binary`. You can set this in the `setting.json` file in your working directory with the `r.rtem.option` parameter:

```
{
    "r.rterm.linux": "/your/conda/env/bin/radian",
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-save",
        "--no-restore",
        "--r-binary=/your/conda/env/bin/R"
    ]
}
```